# Want To Parse Out The Modal # for a Carousel on a Home Page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

There is a carousel on a home page and I would like to add an `onclick event` to it to send the data back to `GA.`  Each part of the carousel is a link. But I want to specify which selection on the carousel they selected.  When I hover over each of the carousel links, the end of the URL says

```
#carousel-modal1, #carousel-modal2, #carousel-modal3, #carousel-modal4, #carousel-modal5.
```

How do I programmatically get the number of modal that's selected?

I would like to add an `onclick` event with a function. When I tried, I added the `onclick` to the rest of the code below.  I know how to send the info back to `GA` but I guess the most important question is how do get that `modal #?`

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <a 
        id="modal-111" 
        href="#carousel-modal" 
        onclick="myFunction()" 
        role="button" 
        data-toggle="modal">
        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="" src="/somepic.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kinda all over the place, but it seems like the prevailing idea is that you want to get `111` from the example via the `onclick` event...

To do that, you can use `this`, which provides access the element that activated the click. Then you can use some js string magic to get the number, like so:

```
function myFunction(){
    var id = this.id;
    var number = id.substring(id.indexOf('-')+1,id.length);
}
```

---

As a sidenote, you may want to consider using [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp), it makes stuff like this way easier:

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <a 
        id="modal-111" 
        href="#carousel-modal" 
        role="button" 
        data-toggle="modal">
        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="" src="/somepic.png" />
    </a>
</div>

<!-- include the jQuery code on your site -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel-item a').click(function(){
            var id = this.id;
            var number = id.substring(id.indexOf('-')+1,id.length);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this example, you're attaching a function to all anchor links inside `carousel-item` tags, so you don't need to add an onclick to each one.

---

And based on your update in the comments, it seems like you want the number that follows the `href` attribute. Here's how to do that:

```
function myFunction(){
    var href = this.getAttribute( 'href' );
    var number = href.substring( href.indexOf('modal')+1, href.length );
}
```

Take a look at how this answer changed based on what you asked. What you were really looking for was answers to two small problems:

1. How to get the value of an attribute.
2. How to search within that value, or how to search a string.

Both of these questions are easily answered with google.

As you build more advanced things, the SO community is not going to spend time deciphering your question.

Next time, be sure to spend a lot of time simplifying your question to the bare essentials. Make sure it is as easy to understand as possible. Also be sure to create a working example (or as close as you can get) of your code on jsfiddle or codepen.

You should aim to spend at least an hour writing a question. If you take this advice, 99% of the time you will answer your own question before you need to post it here, and that will save you a lot of time. Good luck.

Comment: great.  Let me test it out.  I'll be back.

Comment: Let me give more details.  The carousel have 5 images that rotate.  The first image is not a link.  So, that leaves 2-5. When the 2nd image is clicked it goes to somepage.aspx#carousel-modal3, 3rd image - somepage.aspx#carousel-modal4, 4th image somepage.aspx#carousel-modal5, and 5th image - somepage.aspx#carousel-modal6. Would your example still work for my further explanation?  I really want to capture the number that is directly after the word modal.

Comment: I updated the post to show the answer using `href` instead of `id`.